# No Authentication Agent Found Although Already Running

Tags: security, sudo, authentication, alpine-linux, polkit

I have an Alpine-Linux based system (PostmarketOS) running with the LXQT DE.
Ever since I set up the system, out of the box it came with a bunch of problems with user authentication. I have various problems, including:

- Whenever I plug in a USB thumb drive, I get a message saying "Error: not authorized to perform operation."
- If I try to run any downloaded program such as Gparted which requires authentication, I don't get a popup message prompting for my password, and instead get the message "Error executing command as another user: No authentication agent found."
- If I try to edit the user settings with any built-in tools such as the LXQT Configuration Center, I get the same error.
  [image]

After investigating this for a while, I noticed that it seems like the authentication agent is already running. It's set to autostart and I can see it running in the system monitor:
[image]

If I try to run `pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) | lxqt-sudo gparted` then I get the popup to finally appear: [image]

Therefore, I have reason to believe that the required programs are on my system since I see them running and I'm able to run them manually with the command line.

However, I am unable to figure out why the sudo GUI frontend never pops up automatically when an application is requesting superuser permissions, and why I can't perform basic actions such as using my USB thumb drive or change system settings.

I set the root user password and logged in to the root user account, and don't face any of these issues there. So there is something wrong with the setup for the authentication agent or polkit in general and I'm not sure what to do. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.